# How to create a dump of stored procedures/functions/triggers from rds database to local

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

How can i export the dump of procedures/functions/triggers from a mysql databsae in RDS to my local machine. I tried the below command but nothing is happening.

> mysqldump -h rds.host.name -u remote_user_name -p remote_db --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt  > outputfile.sql

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, closing this. The above command worked perfectly, But it took some time.